# Scroll over Contact map

Tags: html, google-maps, drupal, scroll

I am using drupal and a contact map from google maps.
As I scroll down and the mouse hovers over the map it doesnt
continue scrolling but it strarts zooming out , which is annoying.
Is it possible to disable the initial zoom ?

Answer (score 1):

You can scrollwheel option to false within the MapOptions properties

```
options = $.extend({
    scrollwheel: false,
    navigationControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    scaleControl: false,
    draggable: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}, options);
```

You can read about more over [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#MapOptions)